# How to divide Flask app.py in multiple files

Tags: python

My Flask app.py consists of a lot of different pages, with a lot of code.
So I would like to have every different page in a different file and then import it.
So for example, I would have something like this:

`@main.route('/login') from login import login`

And of course, the function login is in the login file. And I have imported all the files in the app.py app with:
`sys.path.insert(0, '/home/abel/flask_app/app/main_files')`

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/abel/flask_app/app/app.py", line 30
    from login import login
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

This code works for me in every other python file, just not in my app.py file. I have already changed the main_files name from main. Maybe this name was already reserved or something. I have already Googled for this question, but I couldn't find any answer relating to this.

I would like to just import the files, instead of using blueprints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```py
# ... declare main

from login import login

main.route('/login')(login)
```

Notice there is no `@` on the start of the line. That's because decorators in Python can be either used with this syntactic sugar, or without like above. Otherwise, you would have to declare a function just to forward the call :

```py
# ... declare main

from login import login

@main.route('/login')
def route_login():
    login(...)
```

Comment: Wow thanks man, this works! I din't know you could set the name of a function at the end of the route.

Comment: @Abel the `@` is just for simplicity, but a decorator is a kind a functions, which take a function as parameter (the wrappee) and return another function (the wrapper). If you look at how they are commonly implemented, you will see there is nothing magical.

Comment: thanks for your answer! It works really well now. I was just struggling with that I couldn't give any parameters to function (the wrappee). But I believe I just found a solution for this. Thanks for your help!